# Mysql Recursive Query Not Returning Parent

Tags: mysql, sql

I've created a nested commenting system like so:

```
id
user_id
comment
comment_date
parent_comment_id
```

And I am trying to get a thread of comments by there parent ids. My query is as such:

```
with recursive cte (id, user_id, comment, comment_date, parent_comment_id) as (
  select     id,
             user_id,
             comment,
             comment_id,
             parent_comment_id
  from       comments
  where      parent_comment_id = 'MES-738fc5be20b24b57978b3e873237ef12'
  union all
  select     c.id,
             c.user_id,
             c.comment,
             c.comment_date,
             c.comment_parent_id
  from       comments c
  inner join cte
          on c.parent_comment_id = cte.id 
)
select * from cte
```

The works except it does not return the first parent comment, which has a parent_comment_id of null. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly, you want `where id = 'MES-738fc5be20b24b57978b3e873237ef12'` instead of `where parent_comment_id = 'MES-738fc5be20b24b57978b3e873237ef12'`

Comment: It already says `parent_comment_id = 'MES-738fc5be20b24b57978b3e873237ef12'`

Comment: @DevinDixon . . . Sample data would help in visualizing what is happening.  For instance, what is the difference between `id` and `comment_id`?  That seems redundant in a table called `comments`.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you simply want a different anchor:

```
select id, user_id, comment, comment_id, parent_comment_id
from comments
where id = 'MES-738fc5be20b24b57978b3e873237ef12'
```